# Ruby - no implicit conversion of HTTParty::Response into String exotel api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version, typeerror, httparty, exotel-api

I'm unable to fetch response or send request to exotel sms api using the provided documentation on exotel rubygem http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/exotel/0.2

The documentations says to fetch response as follows:

```
sms = Exotel::Sms.details(sms_id)
```

But when I do that with an sms_id, ex. sms_id='12345678901234567890' 
like

```
sms = Exotel::Sms.details("12345678901234567890")
```

it gives an error

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of HTTParty::Response into String
```

I do have httparty gem installed. How to solve this?

Comment: 'exotel' was last updated on February 23, 2013. There is a good chance that it is expecting a different version on httpary. In the source for this gem they are using  httparty (0.10.2). I would try changing httparty to that version and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 3):

The library is tested with `0.9.0` version of `httparty` that used to respond with `Hash` for http requests and the code is assuming it is `string` if not Hash and that is why it is failing

Here is the line causing the problem

[exotel/response.rb](https://github.com/vijendra/exotel/blob/66e665209e05bb74cfe6d5f7b2650f4129b2ed50/lib/exotel/response.rb#L7)

Quick fix would be to use 'httparty=0.9.0'

You may do it by using

```
gem "httparty","0.9.0"
```

Here is a working sample code, please update the account_sid and token with yours

```
gem "httparty","0.9.0"
require "exotel"

account_sid = "testexotel"
token = "9dcb4*******************e1dc2174fc47" 

Exotel.configure do |c|
  c.exotel_sid   = account_sid
  c.exotel_token = token
end

sms = Exotel::Sms.details("40a7*********258d411898b18b")
puts sms.status
puts sms.date_sent
```

Comment: It is nit official exotel ruby library. I would suggest using a newer library `gem install exotel-api-client` is last updated 2 yrs back